# URL Rewrite Rule (subfolder .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I have this .htaccess file

```
domain.com/modules/mymodule/.htaccess
```

can this htaccess file "handle" urls like `domain.com/something`

i cannot put or edit a .htaccess on the root directory, i can only put it in mymodule subfolder

---

i don't want the user to see

```
domain.com/modules/mymodule/mymodulepage
```

but something like

```
domain.com/mymodulepage
```

can this be done ?

i posted nothing that i tried because they were just desperate attempts such as playing with RewriteBase and so on .. but i knew that the url is not getting "handled" by the subfolder's htaccess file !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can this htaccess file "handle" urls like domain.com/something

No it can't. It won't be accessed unless the request is for something in that directory or its subdirectories.

You can make `domain.com/modules/mymodule/mymodulepage` redirect to `domain.com/mymodulepage`, but once it's there, you won't have any rules to property handle it.

If you have no access to any kind of server config except an htaccess file in `/modules/mymodule/`, you're not going to be able to do this. If you do have access to some level of config, you could do something like this:

```
Alias /mymodulepage /the/path/to/modules/mymodule/
```

And that will point the URI `/mymodulepage` to the file-path `/the/path/to/modules/mymodule/` where the URI `/modules/mymodule/` is.